# Delete useraccount with rules based on value filled during creation of account

Tags: users, rules

Does someone have a solution/description for my wish to delete (fake) user accounts that almost always fill in the (phone-number) string 12345 or 123456.

I already have a rule that sends me an message when a new account is created, but I cant find the option to delete account when using rules.

PS I already us the module Toboggan.

Comment: As hint for filling in the telephone number I ask a full phone-number including the land-line number, every day I get user accounts that wait for admin approval that have the "phone-number" 12345 and 123456 filled in. I want to delete those user accounts immediately. The (most of the time) known users  that i accept, don't fill in that "phone-number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Events use "After saving a new user account" event
In Conditions use "Data comparison"
IN Actions use "Delete entity"

I have not tried it, but hope this will work..!!

Additional rules are available at https://drupal.org/project/rb

Comment: Just looked at your proposal..first issue was that I only can compare with one string (cant select "contains"), but I can work around that by making to conditions (one comparing with string 12345, the other with 123456. The second issue is that it seems that I only can compare with other datafields? Not with values I typed in myself?

Comment: This suggestion solved my issue. I didn't need an extra entity rule module.

Comment: The comparison of the variable can be specified more specific by selecting: Contain/begin/end/regular expression. Now all users profiles that fill in 12345 somewhere in the telephone field are removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [Entity Rules](https://drupal.org/project/entity_rules) module which will add entity related actions: create entity, delete entity, fetch entity by ID, etc.

You are not only limited to users, but to any other entities you have on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [spamicide](https://drupal.org/project/spamicide) module, it essentially does what you are talking about. When you add spamicide to a form, it adds an extra field to the form, and then hides it using CSS. A human would never fill out the form as they cant see it, but Spam Bots loading pages would fill in the form. Every submission with the hidden field filled out is automatically denied.

This wouldn't do anything to accounts that are already signed up, but I use it on some of my bigger sites that were getting 20 to 30 spam sign ups a day, and now there isn't a single one.

Comment: I already have installed the spamicide module, so I'm not sure if these are real humans or very intelligent scripts that bypass the hidden spamicide field and are still able to create a user account.

Comment: In the spamicide settings, have you changed the names of the fields? If you change them to something like "first_name" it is less likely a bot script would ignore it.

Comment: If you mean the fieldname that must be remain empty in order to be able to create an account: Yes I have, named it something like birthdaydate...